# How many Steiner Symmetrizations does it take to make an arbitrary set convex?

Tags: geometry, analysis, partial-differential-equations, convex-geometry, rearrangement-inequality

I have not seen this question investigated before but I might be wrong:

1. Can any subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ be turned into a convex set by *finitely* many steiner symmetrizations?
2. If yes, is the number of symmetrizations necessarily bounded, i.e. does there exist a dimensional constant such that it will always take at most $m_d$ symmetrizations (this would be interesting)
3. If no, what is a counterexample, i.e. a set that can not be made convex within a finite number of symmetrizations?

I hope somebody knows something, this is super a interesting situation for me.
Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 1):

[Koch's snow flake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake) needs an infinite number of Steiner symmetrizations.

Comment: Thank you very much? Could you point me to a proof of this or sketch it?

Comment: In fact, the generating process of Koch's snowflake (at least a certain version of it) that we could call "successive invaginations" can be considered as exactly the inverse of Steiner symmetrisations. Therefore, as there are an infinite number of invagination steps... I think other fractal shapes as the Dragon curve would have the same impossibility.

Comment: I don't doubt it but just to be clear about it: Is this something that you know proof of or is it an intuition/heuristic based result?

Comment: I agree : what I said must be precised. In its present state, it is too vague.

Comment: This is speculation but: If d=2 and we symmetrize along the x and y axis then we essentially have a union of symmetric-in-both-axes rectangles. If we symmetrize any union of 2 such rectangles in x+y and x-y direction we get a convex set. Of course this doesbt necessarily work on the uncountable union but... maybe there is a way